# Meteor MongoDB Setting field of array per document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a `Documents` in a `Collection` that have a field that is an `Array` (foo). This is an `Array` of other `subdocuments`. I want to set the same field (bar) for each `subdocument` in each `document` to the same value. This value comes from a checkbox.

So..my client-side code is something like

```
'click #checkAll'(e, template) {
    const target = e.target;
    const checked = $(target).prop('checked');

    //Call Server Method to update list of Docs
    const docIds = getIds();
    Meteor.call('updateAllSubDocs', docIds, checked);
 }
```

I tried using [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#positional-update-all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[])

And came up with the following for my Server helper method.

```
'updateAllSubDocs'(ids, checked) {
     Items.update({ _id: { $in: ids } }, { $set: { "foo.$[].bar": bar } },
      { multi: true }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          throw new Meteor.Error('error updating');
        }
      });
 }
```

But that throws an error 'foo.$[].bar is not allowed by the Schema'. Any ideas?
I'm using SimpleSchema for both the parent and subdocument

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some example data and schema, recent versions of MongoDB allow you to update the document with the value according to the current document

Comment: If your question focuses only on checkbox values, which I assume are boolean values, you can split the bulk update into 2 groups, one with `true` the other with `false` values

Comment: might also make sense to only update the checkboxes that change depending on your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing an option to bypass Simple Schema. It might be lacking support for this (somewhat) newer Mongo feature.

`bypassCollection2`

Example:

```
Items.update({ _id: { $in: ids } }, { $set: { "foo.$[].bar": bar } },
      { multi: true, bypassCollection2: true }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          throw new Meteor.Error('error updating');
        }
      });
```

Old answer:

Since you say you need to make a unique update for each document it sounds like bulk updating is the way to go in this case. Here's an example of how to do this in Meteor.

```
if (docsToUpdate.length < 1) return
const bulk = MyCollection.rawCollection().initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
for (const myDoc of docsToUpdate) {
  bulk.find({ _id: myDoc._id }).updateOne({ $set: update })
}
Promise.await(bulk.execute()) // or use regular await if you want...
```

Note we exit the function early if there's no docs because `bulk.execute()` throws an exception if there's no operations to process.

Comment: Just clarified my question as I realized I'm changing the same value per each Doc

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added that option in but am now getting, "MinimongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query". Which is strange, I don't know why MiniMongo is complaining.

Comment: Nm, I had to wrap the `Update` in a `Meteor.isServer`. I'm marking this as accepted. But are there any implications for bypassing SimpleSchema? In my case there doesn't seem to be much risk as I'm just updating one field, but wanted to know your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: First, make sure you're using the newest Simple Schema (from npm, not the Meteor package). You may need to change your code to support that if you were using the meteor package. Then if the problem is still there I would recommend to file an issue on Simple Schema Github repo because this is a bug. It should support the Mongo syntax that was introduced in version 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

If your data have different data in the $set for each entry on array, I think you need a loop in server side.

Mongo has Bulk operations, but I don't know if you can call them using `Collection.rawCollection().XXXXX`
 I've used `rawCollection()` to access aggregate and it works fine to me. Maybe work with bulk operations.